# Installation Exchange Server 2016 failed

Tags: windows, exchange-2016

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2

Exchange Version: 2016

When I install Exchange, I get this error at the end: "The user isn't logged on to an Active Directory domain".

How can we log the Administrator to an Active Directory domain? I'm very new at server administration.

Comment: Have you tried using the Domain Administrator username and password, rather than the local computer Administrator account? These are two very different accounts...

Comment: "How can we log the Administrator to an Active Directory domain?" Honestly, if you have to ask this, then Exchange administration is well beyond your current abilities;  you should probably step back and learn about AD domains first.

Answer (score 1):

From the Microsoft article entitled "[The current account isn't logged into an Active Directory domain](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms.exch.setupreadiness.loggedontodomain(v=exchg.160).aspx)" from the TechNet section "Exchange 2016 readiness checks":

> Microsoft Exchange Server 2016 Setup can’t continue because it detected that the current account isn’t logged on to an Active Directory domain. You must log in using an Active Directory account that has the permissions required to install Exchange Server 2016.
>
> Setup requires that the user who is logged on when Exchange 2016 is installed has permission to create and modify objects in Active Directory. If you’re running Exchange 2016 Setup in your organization for the first time, the account you use must be a member of the Schema Admins and Enterprise Admins groups. These permissions are required because Active Directory is prepared for Exchange 2016 the first time Setup is run. After Active Directory is prepared, the account you use to install additional Exchange 2016 servers must be a member of the Organization Management management role group.
>
> To resolve this issue, grant the logged-on user the appropriate permissions, or log on with an account that has those permissions and run Exchange 2016 Setup again.

So ensure you are logging in using an AD administrator account (that's been granted the permissions explained in the article above), instead of an administrator account that's local to the Exchange Server.

This will require the Exchange server being properly joined to an Active Directory domain, so if you don't have one of those yet, then you should [start there](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20834.windows-2012-r2-active-directory-installation.aspx).

> How can we log the Administrator to an Active Directory domain?

If your Exchange server is already properly joined to the AD domain, then when you type in your user name to log in, it should assume you are using a AD domain account by default. So if it's joined, and you're managing to log in as a local account, then you're apparently specifying the local machine account on purpose (using `.\administrator`, or 'machineName\administrator` for example). So stop doing that and just type in your AD administrator user name and password instead. :)

For a bit more reading, here's a decent article discussing the differences between local and domain accounts:

[Local vs Domain User Accounts](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/netgeneral/Local-vs-Domain-User-Accounts.html)